# Compiler is unable to resolve a matching class method passed via std::mem_fn

Tags: c++, templates, overloading, pointer-to-member, overload-resolution

Consider [the following code](https://gist.github.com/pozdneev/c98135fa9e75c9b3f8e31355d5f03a3d):

```cpp
struct A {
    int& getAttribute();
    const int& getAttribute() const;
};

std::vector<int> foo(const std::vector<A>& as) {
    std::vector<int> ints;
    std::transform(as.begin(), as.end(), std::back_inserter(ints),
                   std::mem_fn(&A::getAttribute));
    return ints;
}
```

Its compilation (`g++ -std=c++14 -c mem_fn.cpp`, g++ version 7.5.0) fails with the following error:

```
error: no matching function for call to
‘mem_fn(<unresolved overloaded function type>)’
```

However,

- If we [keep](https://gist.github.com/pozdneev/ea5c3f1b7481127bbcf7b739aa582fbb) only the `const int& getAttribute() const` method, the compilation succeeds
- If we [keep](https://gist.github.com/pozdneev/a55fc2328ecd534a6694ab31e9a51883) only the `int& getAttribute()` method, the compilation fails with the following error messages:

  ```
  /usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_algo.h:4306:24:
       error: no match for call to
       ‘(std::_Mem_fn<int& (A::*)()>) (const A&)’
  /usr/include/c++/7/functional:174:27:
       error: no matching function for call to
       ‘__invoke(int& (A::* const&)(), const A&)’
  /usr/include/c++/7/bits/invoke.h:89:5:
       error: no type named ‘type’ in
       ‘struct std::__invoke_result<int& (A::* const&)(), const A&>’
  ```

Alternatively, we could use a lambda here or help the compiler by [explicitly specifying](https://gist.github.com/pozdneev/6309c767402ae2d6385b349e454384db) the type of a matching method as `mem_fn`'s template argument:
`std::mem_fn<const int& () const>(&A::getAttribute)`.

So, it looks like, as the `int& getAttribute()` method does not fit, the `const int& getAttribute() const` method is the one that should have been choosen by the by the compiler in the original code.
Why does compiler fail to select it and report the `<unresolved overloaded function type>` error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler should choose pointer of the function at the moment of `mem_fn` creation. It can only look at the `std::mem_fn(&A::getAttribute)` expression, but cannot look up how it's used. It's possible to work around with [user-defined conversion operators](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Return_Type_Resolver), but is generally not done.

So, your reasoning about future uses of this `mem_fn` does not apply.

You have to specify the exact overload of `&A::getAttribute` to use. `static_cast` to a fixed type will work (it's a special case where unresolved overloaded functions are permitted):

```cpp
  std::transform(
      as.begin(), as.end(), std::back_inserter(ints),
      std::mem_fn(static_cast<const int &(A::*)() const>(&A::getAttribute)));
```